# Add/remove RadioButton

Tags: c#, wpf

In my program I use for WPF **ListBox** to display the **RadioButton**. There are two buttons "Add post" and "Delete post".

I can add item, but there are two questions:

1) How to position the cursor (point) after the addition on the new item?

2) How to delete the selected item and position the cursor to the previous?

[image]

```
// Add element
private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        RadioButton obj = new RadioButton();
        obj.Content = "Group " + ++numberOfGroups;
        ListBox1.Items.Add(obj);
}

// Remove element
private void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //..
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Thanks for answers, but your code works fine for the List elements. By **Position the Cursor** I mean, that I need to select a radio button, not element of the list. May be it will be more clear with this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Adding or deleting items by the c# codebehind will be done in each `Page_load()`, which means the user won't see it done - he'll only see the fixed lists after the action on the load, and the old one before it.

Comment: @A.Abramov Its WPF not ASP.net

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve here. By "position the cursor" do you mean "moving the mouse cursor automatically" ?

Comment: @Shaharyar My bad. The window is still loaded - so the concept is still relevant.

Comment: Do you want `RadioButton` to be checked as well?

Comment: @dima, please view edit for my answer, I've changed it to select RadioButtons. Hope, it helps

Comment: @VMaleev I've already changed component radioButon to component listBoxItem and now it works, but thanks, your answer is very useful too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean **Selection of an item** by **Position the Cursor**. You can do it easily by getting the last index of `ItemsCollection` of `ListBox`:

```
// Add element
private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //add new item
    RadioButton obj = new RadioButton();
    obj.Content = "Group " + ++numberOfGroups;
    ListBox1.Items.Add(obj);

    //select last item
    int LastItemIndex = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1;
    ListBox1.SelectedItem = ListBox1.Items.GetItemAt(LastItemIndex);
}

// Remove element
private void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //delete selected item
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex);

    //select last item
    int LastItemIndex = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1;
    ListBox1.SelectedItem = ListBox1.Items.GetItemAt(LastItemIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If "position the cursor" means "select item", then:

```
    private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton obj = new RadioButton();
        obj.Content = "Group " + ++numberOfGroups;
        ListBox1.Items.Add(obj);
        ListBox1.SelectedItem = obj;
        obj.IsChecked = true;
        ListBox1.Focus();
    }

    private void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            int position = ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(ListBox1.SelectedItem);

            ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem);

            if (ListBox1.Items.Count == 0) return;

            if (position == 0)
            {
                ListBox1.SelectedItem = ListBox1.Items[0];
            }
            else
            {
                ListBox1.SelectedItem = ListBox1.Items[position - 1];
            }

            (ListBox1.SelectedItem as RadioButton).IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
```